# VIsual Studio 2010, easily maximize/minimize editor?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there an easy way to maximize *and* minimize/restore an editor in Visual Studio ?

To demonstrate, I'm looking for what Eclipse has:

**Normal Layout:**

[image: Eclipse Standard]

Hit a key combo and you get this (This seems somewhat like Windows->AutoHide all in VS2010)

**Maximized Editor**
[image: Eclipse Maximized Editor]

Now, another key combo , and you get back to the **Normal Layout**. That's the important thing(Windows->AutoHide all in Visual Studio just leaves windows around, not allowing you to *quickly* switch back and forth.)

Is there anything like this in VS2010 ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

View/FullScreen (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> here) will make the editor window use the whole screen. That might be a bit more than what you asked for, but then the same keyboard shortcut will reverse this again, so it's quite easy.

Comment: I'd prefer it not to go actually fullscreen, hiding the taskbar too - but that'll do

Comment: @Anonym: Just don't put your IDE on the monitor where the taskbar is, then. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

Alt + W + U
will Hide all windows.

Comment: At least in VS2019 there is no menu entry with mnemonic 'U'  in menu "Window". I guess it was the command `Window.AutoHideAll` which is good to maximize the editor but I did not find a way to unhide them. Is there something? This toggle with Ctrl+M from Eclipse was great.

Answer (score 2):

Alt-Shift-Enter makes the editor full screen and enlarges it. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a keyboard shortcut for this but if you ctrl+click on the window tab you should be able to maximize code window within IDE instead of full screen. This will be equivalent functionality to Eclipse ctrl+m shortcut.