# Remove File Menu Toolbar from Visual Studio (Menu Bar)

Tags: visual-studio, toolbar

To increase working space and remove unused items from the Toolbar area, I would like to remove the File/Edit/View/etc toolbar (aka the Menu Bar) from the top of Visual Studio (2008 and 2010) (I don't use any of those, I try to use keystrokes for everything).  Is there a way to do this?

This is similar to TinyMenu for Firefox, but I would setting for just removing the toolbar entirely: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1455/

EDIT:

If you right click the toolbar and go to customize the Menu Bar can not be de-selected:

[image]

Comment: I feel the same way about mouse clicks and menus - give me keyboard shortcuts and I'm a happy camper.

Comment: How old is this machine?  Well, the monitor?  Dell 21.5" 1920x1080 for $170

Comment: User Experience is important no matter how big the display. (Which happens to be a 22" widescreen monitor)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this extension should help with that.

[Hide Main Menu Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813/)

Haven't tested it myself though.

Comment: Works perfectly. Hides by default, shows up when you either hold ALT hold press and ALT-key combination. Thanks!

Comment: The version linked above does not work in vs2017. Here is a link to the 2017 version: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AaronHoffman.HideMainMenu2017

Answer (score 4):

If you really want space, click on View and then click on Full Screen.

Comment: Or use the shortcut Shift+Alt+Enter. Mentioned for example in [Visual Studio 2010, easily maximize/minimize editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933944/visual-studio-2010-easily-maximize-minimize-editor).

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the menu bar and select Customize...  The Customize dialog should pop up.  Then you can take each top level menu item and drag it from the menu bar to the dialog.  Nothing more efficient comes to my mind at the moment.

Comment: even with all the items removed from the "Menu Bar" it still takes up space and can not be de-selected

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2008: the best solution would be to: MOVE all the GUI controls 'individually' to the menu bar by dragging with the 'Alt' button held, since you can not move entire tool-bars in to the menu bar at-once. Additionally you can add other required controls in to the menu bar column and can also customize its icon via:
**Tools** > **Customize** > [**Click**-to-select-control] > **Modify Selection** > **Change Button Image**.
This way you will have **only one column** for all the buttons, typically recommended for a wide-screen. Also to remove any Item from the menu bar: you can Alt+Drag away the menu bar Items like "File", "Help" individually to make space.